# mysql 5.6 gtid replication slave stuck (system lock)?

Tags: mysql, replication, gtid

I have set up 5.6 gtid based replication (on 5.6.26) it seemed to work when I did it, it replicated my random test db over that I created beside normal data. 
However at some point something must have happened because all I see is this:

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: System lock
                  Master_Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                  Master_User: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysqld-bin.000141
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 169293671
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000003
                Relay_Log_Pos: 16861206
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysqld-bin.000141
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 16860994
              Relay_Log_Space: 169298584
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 55203
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: 7846a847-62c7-11e5-91a6-e06995de432e
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: System lock
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 7846a847-62c7-11e5-91a6-e06995de432e:4757140-5030085
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 7846a847-62c7-11e5-91a6-e06995de432e:1-4783274
                Auto_Position: 1
```

now originally "Slave_SQL_Running_State" said "reading event from relay log" or something like that, it has now changed to system lock as well (IO state always said that).

It seems the `Seconds_Behind_Master` is increasing steadily, and the relay log grows rapidly in size on the filesystem, while `Executed_gtid_set` does seem to change, but still something seems wrong because it is just so much behind....

Here's the processlist:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+---------------------------------------+------------------+
| Id   | User        | Host      | db   | Command | Time  | State                                 | Info             |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+---------------------------------------+------------------+
| 1877 | root        | localhost | NULL | Sleep   |  6076 |                                       | NULL             |
| 1878 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query   |     0 | init                                  | show processlist |
| 1886 | system user |           | NULL | Connect |   783 | System lock                           | NULL             |
| 1887 | system user |           | NULL | Connect |     0 | System lock                           | NULL             |
| 1888 | system user |           | NULL | Connect |   783 | Waiting for an event from Coordinator | NULL             |
| 1889 | system user |           | NULL | Connect | 55455 | System lock                           | NULL             |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+---------------------------------------+------------------+
```

I tried to stop the slave and start it again but it didnt help.

Does anybody have any ideas what I could try to make this work again? Would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Question 1 : Are you running MySQL on Windows ?

Comment: Question 2 : Did you run `LOAD DATA INFILE` on the Master ?

Comment: Hi, No i dont do LOAD DATA INFILE, I have read that post from you earlier, but it is not the case in my setup, and I am running both servers on debian jessie, Ill look into the multi threaded nature of this, thanks for the advice, If I run it like that it is unintentional :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I see more than 2 `system user` entries in the processlist, I would assume you are using Multi-Threaded Replication ([**slave_parallel_workers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#sysvar_slave_parallel_workers) > 1).

That looks like a bug

- [Bug #73066 : Replication stall with multi-threaded replication](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73066)
- [Bug #72794 : Relay log without xid_log_event may case parallel replication hang](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72794)

On Oct 29, 2014, this was expressed by `David Moss`

> Thank you for your feedback. This issue was covered in bug 17326020 and the following was added to the MySQL 5.6.21 and 5.7.5 changelogs:
>
> When the I/O thread reconnected to a master using GTIDs and
>   multithreaded slaves while in the middle of a transaction, it failed
>   to abort the transaction, leaving a partial transaction in the relay
>   log, and then retrieving the same transaction again. This occurred
>   when performing a rotation of the relay log. Now when reconnecting,
>   the server checks before rotating the log in such cases, and waits
>   first for any ongoing transaction to complete.
>
> Therefore nothing new will be added to cover this bug and I'm closing it as fixed.

On Dec 10, 2014, this was expressed by `Laurynas Biveinis`

> Problem:
>
> With MTS, GTIDs and auto positioning enabled, when a worker applies a
>   partial transaction left on relaylog by an IO thread reconnection, it
>   will wait for the XID log event to commit the transaction.
>
> Unfortunately, the SQL thread coordinator will reach the master's
>   ROTATE event on the next relaylog file and will wait for all workers
>   to finish their tasks before applying the ROTATE.
>
> Analysis:
>
> As the whole transaction is retrieved again by the IO thread after the
>   reconnection, the slave must rollback the partial transaction once
>   noticing this ROTATE from the master.
>
> This bug reports the same issue already fixed by BUG#17326020, and the
>   reported issue is not reproducible anymore. So, this patch is just
>   adding a new test case.

## SUGGESTION

Run `FLUSH BINARY LOGS;` on the Master

See if the movement triggers a response from the SQL threads.

If it does not, go ahead and remove [**slave_parallel_workers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#sysvar_slave_parallel_workers) from `my.cnf` and restart mysql.

Since you started MySQL up and master and slave and got `error 1236`, that means you are trying to establish replication from an impossible position. In the context of GTID and error message you got, the binary logs needed to fully identify a set of queries within a GTID set no longer exists,

Look back at your `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`

```
Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 7846a847-62c7-11e5-91a6-e06995de432e:4757140-5030085
 Executed_Gtid_Set: 7846a847-62c7-11e5-91a6-e06995de432e:1-4783274
```

From this, the last GTID executed is `7846a847-62c7-11e5-91a6-e06995de432e:4783274`

This means that the binary log that has or had `7846a847-62c7-11e5-91a6-e06995de432e:4783275` no longer exists.

I can see this happening if you stopped replication on the Slave, left replication off long enough for the Master to rotate its binary logs (via expire_logs_days) the slave still needed to see, then turned on replication.

In your particular case, try doing a mysqlbinlog dump of the binary log `mysqld-bin.000141`. If nothing comes out of it, you will have to reload the Slave and setup replication from scratch.

Comment: Hi,FLUSH BINARY LOGS didnt seem to change anything, so do I understand it corrently that if I set slave_parallel_workers to 1 that would disable the mult threaded processing? should just a restart after putting this to my.cnf on the slave get me going?

Comment: Hi, I have removed slave_parallel_workers from the slave my.cnf, restarted mysql on the slave, but still getting system lock for both the IO and the SQL thread (SQL thread says "update" for a sec then went back to system lock)

Comment: now I restarted both master and slave, and now i am getting this as IO error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Found old binary log without GTIDs while looking for the oldest binary log that contains any GTID that is not in the given gtid set'

Comment: Did you at any point switch from GTID to non- GTID and back ?

Comment: no, I have installed both of these servers fresh, enabled gtid, and then used an ordinary dump to load the data, then used innobackupex on it to create a slave. that's it. The SQL thread is still running btw, it is just the IO thread that stopped

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I have just set this whole thing up 2 days ago, os I guess it is about time to start from scratch :) I have not stopped replicaiton rather it was stuck on this system lock for the last 14 hours :( anyway, I hope with the multithreaded replication off, I wont have to rebuild this every 2 days :(

Comment: Hi, I recreated the slave from scratch yesterday, with parallel workers off. This time it lasted about 14 hours. This is starting to happen again, SQL_running_state says "reading event from the relay log" and IO_state is in system lock again.... Any ideas? Replication is not too useful if I have to rebuild it every day :(

Comment: Eh, this is pretty hectic, now the accumulated ~1800 second delay disappeared quite quickly, going back to 0, and then immediately started going up again, is this normal?

Comment: ok, this is totally screwed now... I tried changing the open_files_limit (currently 1024) on the master by adding a line to the my.cnf, then restarted mysql, and now I am getting the 1236 gtid error on the slave again... just for restarting the master???? wth?

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the GTID event that's being processed? I ask, because "SYSTEM LOCK" is typically the thread state you will see when a big LOAD DATA INFILE statement is being processed. So it could simply be that the thread(s) are streaming/executing a huge event like that.

See:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69375

If that's the case, then restarting mysqld or the slave threads will only have caused the long process to start over again. :(