# Mysql Master Slave replication performance is too low

Tags: mysql, performance, replication

I have implemented Master Slave Replication.

The slave can't keep up with progress.

How can I find out the problem and optimize the config?

> OS: CentOS 6.8
>  Mysql 5.6.35
>  Master => Slave 3-5 Mbps
>
> ```
>            Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
>               Master_Host: **.**.**.**
>               Master_User: ********
>               Master_Port: 3306
>             Connect_Retry: 60
>           Master_Log_File: binlog.000095
>       Read_Master_Log_Pos: 297639485
>            Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000050
>             Relay_Log_Pos: 644337677
>     Relay_Master_Log_File: binlog.000083
>          Slave_IO_Running: Yes
>         Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
>           Replicate_Do_DB:
>       Replicate_Ignore_DB:
>        Replicate_Do_Table:
>    Replicate_Ignore_Table:
>   Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
>                Last_Errno: 0
>                Last_Error:
>              Skip_Counter: 0
>       Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 644337473
>           Relay_Log_Space: 13252726053
>           Until_Condition: None
>            Until_Log_File:
>             Until_Log_Pos: 0
>        Master_SSL_Allowed: No
>        Master_SSL_CA_File:
>        Master_SSL_CA_Path:
>           Master_SSL_Cert:
>         Master_SSL_Cipher:
>            Master_SSL_Key:
>     Seconds_Behind_Master: 119951 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
>             Last_IO_Errno: 0
>             Last_IO_Error:
>            Last_SQL_Errno: 0
>            Last_SQL_Error:   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
>          Master_Server_Id: 1
>               Master_UUID: bada755f-d361-11e6-b53e-d4ae52b21cd5
>          Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
>                 SQL_Delay: 0
>       SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
>   Slave_SQL_Running_State: System lock
>        Master_Retry_Count: 86400
>               Master_Bind:
>   Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
>  Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
>            Master_SSL_Crl:
>        Master_SSL_Crlpath:
>        Retrieved_Gtid_Set: bada755f-d361-11e6-b53e-d4ae52b21cd5:281172-14941959
>         Executed_Gtid_Set: bada755f-d361-11e6-b53e-d4ae52b21cd5:1-11696260
>             Auto_Position: 1
> ```

Comment: have you tested the connection speed between master and slave machine, and how much time it will take to copy anything between those two machines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql 5.6 gtid replication slave stuck (system lock)?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117068/mysql-5-6-gtid-replication-slave-stuck-system-lock)

Comment: This has nothing to do with slow performance. Your replication is stuck. See the line Slave_SQL_Running_State, it says "System lock". Have a look [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117068/mysql-5-6-gtid-replication-slave-stuck-system-lock) for example.

Comment: What versions are Master and Slave?  What OS?

Comment: Hi Eric, first of all check comment from @tombom, need fix this (some time more easy - re-fresh slave from dump), than check next. Information still not answer for all - 3-5 mb more than enough for 10 transactions and extremely slow for 1M. RickJames also ask good question. As much more information in question - as much more easy understand source of error

Comment: Please check the follows: 1. Is IO thread catching up with the master ? 2. if you use more than one database, did you set the parallel replication ? 3. Is there some IO restriction in slave ?